# How to use archive_command to send archives to remote server (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

Im looking into continuous archiving. I have a running test but the archives are getting saved to the master I want to send them to different machine.

my command:

```
archive_command: 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/archive/%f'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything you want. Depends on remote server and access you have to it. Examples:

```
archive_command: 'scp %p postgres@remoteserver:/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/archive/%f'
archive_command: 'rsync -a %p postgres@remoteserver:/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/archive/%f'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used scp worked fine i just had %p in the wrong place.

Comment: There is an explicit warning in the docs that overwrite should not happen, and that a nonzero exit code should be returned if the file does not exist.

Comment: WARNING: if you're gonna use `scp`, keep in mind that if your SSH connection drops in the middle of a transfer you will probably have a partial WAL file on the remote side, but `scp` will return a non-zero status and PostgreSQL will be trying to archive the *same* WAL file unsuccessfully because the file already exists on the remote side, and as overwrite should not happen (as stated by @cmc), this will freeze the whole archiving process. Copying to a temporary location first or using `rsync` solves this problem.